# id not yet working after adcli for Active Directory join on rhel6/7

Tags: centos, active-directory, redhat, sssd

Having done winbind joins but no sssd yet, I'm asked today to use adcli and sssd to join an EL7 box to a windows AD service.

the software, an updated minimal el7 install with adcli, sssd and some krb5 stuff added:

```
adcli-0.8.1-3.el7.x86_64
authconfig-6.2.8-30.el7.x86_64
krb5-libs-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64
krb5-workstation-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64
oddjob-0.31.5-4.el7.x86_64
oddjob-mkhomedir-0.31.5-4.el7.x86_64
python-sssdconfig-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.noarch
samba-client-libs-4.6.2-10.el7_4.x86_64
samba-common-4.6.2-10.el7_4.noarch
samba-common-libs-4.6.2-10.el7_4.x86_64
samba-common-tools-4.6.2-10.el7_4.x86_64
samba-libs-4.6.2-10.el7_4.x86_64
sssd-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-ad-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-client-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-common-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-common-pac-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-dbus-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-ipa-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-krb5-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-krb5-common-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-ldap-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-proxy-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
sssd-tools-1.15.2-50.el7_4.2.x86_64
```

the sssd.conf, in case it helps:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, ssh, sudo
domains = test.domain.com

[nss]
filter_users = root,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus,radiusd,news,nscd,centos,ubuntu

[pam]

[ssh]

[sudo]

[domain/test.domain.com]
enumerate = true

id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad

ad_domain = test.domain.com
krb5_realm = TEST.DOMAIN.COM
cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u

ldap_user_ssh_public_key = sshPublicKey
```

The join itself is handled via adcli:

```
  adcli join --host-fqdn tstel7-01.test.domain.com \
    --computer-name tstel7-01 \
    -U adjoinacct \
    test.domain.com
```

Keytab?  Rich:

```
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 restrictedkrbhost/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01.test.domain.com@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 host/tstel7-01@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 TSTEL7-01$@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 TSTEL7-01$@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 TSTEL7-01$@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 TSTEL7-01$@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
3 TSTEL7-01$@TEST.DOMAIN.COM
```

But, no dice:

```
# id adjoinacct
id: adjoinacct: no such user
```

It can't even find the account used to join it (none, really).

tshark (-plni any not port 22) shows that, during the id run, no connections are going out.

What the heck did I miss?  Any ideas?  Clues?  Can I provide ANY info?  This is baffling and, while I want to bail out and do the samba-winbind thing, it's just not shiny enough for the implementation plan -- and the sssd solution is just so well promoted to be discarded so quickly.

(I can also test on EL6, to same bad result :-( )

(feel free to create and add the 'adcli' tag; I can't)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try

```
id adjoinacct@test.domain.com
```

?

If that works where the previous command did not, then the issue may have to do with the use_fully_qualified_names setting. If you want to be able to use short names, and you don't have multiple domains to worry about, you might try putting

```
use_fully_qualified_names = False
```

under the [domain/test.domain.com] section of sssd.conf, then restarting the sssd service. Yes, man sssd.conf says the default is FALSE, but I've had to explicitly set this to avoid similar issues.

Comment: good catch, but not a fix here.  

# id adjoinacct@test.domain.com
id: adjoinacct@test.domain.com: no such user

Please keep mulling it over, and let me know if I can test anything else.

Answer (score 0):

To have id mappings and logins to create home directories use:

```
authconfig --update --enablesssd --enablesssdauth --enablemkhomedir
```

This modifies the necessary pam files.

You need have the package `oddjob-mkhomedir` rpm installed to create the home directories or else just leave the `--enablemkhomedir` switch off.

Also make sure your `sssd`  service is running.